# Makefile only prints part of echo statement

Tags: makefile, echo

I'm writing my first makefile to compile latex code several ways (using the beamer package), but am stuck at a very basic problem that has nothing even to do with latex. Consider the following MWE of my makefile:

```
test.tex: 
    echo '\input{1-slidepreamble} \changemode{handout}' > Xtest.tex
```

It creates a file Xtest.tex, but the file only contains the text

> \input{1-slidepreamble}

I have no idea why? What's more, when I copy the same line

```
echo '\input{1-slidepreamble} \changemode{handout}' > Xtest.tex
```

into the terminal, it creates a file with both commands in it. I'm lost. Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

**Update:** It seems to have something to do with the `\c` somehow. When I write

```
test2 :
    echo '\input{1-slidepreamble}' > test2.tex 
    echo '\changemode{handout}' >> test2.tex
    echo 'more text' >> test2.tex
    echo '\c see this?' >> test2.tex
```

then it only prints rows 1 and 3 to the file.

Is there a way to write it so the makefile doesn't try to evaluate the `\c` code and just copies it over to the file?

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: When you run make does it print that echo line just as you show it?  What OS are you using?  There's nothing wrong with this makefile, as G.M. says.

Comment: @MadScientist I'm on mac osx and am using the standard terminal (in case this matters, it mentions "-bash" at the top). The terminal prints the full line `echo '\input{1-slidepreamble} \changemode{handout}' > Xtest.tex` but the file just only contains the first part. The only thing nonstandard I can think of is that the folder is located on google drive... I'll test what happens if I put the makefile in my home folder. Update: Same thing happens. Weird...

Comment: Well, all I can suggest is that Apple is known to ship a terribly old version of GNU make, and they've apparently applied their own patches to it that introduce bugs because i've seen other makefiles reported to fail there that work fine with that same older version of GNU make built from unpatched code.  If you're using the MacOS-provided version of GNU make you might consider getting a newer version from MacPorts or Brew or wherever and see if that works.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see your update re `\c`.  What if you run `/bin/sh`, then at that prompt you type the `echo '\change'` ... what does that print?

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is what I'd expect to see (I think) if your `echo` was actually aliased as `echo -e` .

Comment: @MadScientist That prints nothing. How do I un-alias my echo? :)

Comment: It's not an alias.  I think it's a difference between how `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` treats the `echo` program.  Probably `/bin/bash` (your default shell) is using a built-in version of echo and `/bin/sh` (which is the default shell and what `make` will always invoke unless you set the `SHELL` make variable to something else) is using the `/bin/echo` program which behaves differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's the version of `echo` you're using.

It might be a better idea to use `printf` instead?

What if you use:

```
test.tex: 
        printf '%s\n' '\input{1-slidepreamble} \changemode{handout}' > Xtest.tex
```

Comment: This works!! I'll remember to always use printf from here on. Thank you!!

Comment: The POSIX spec only defines `echo` for "simple strings".  Any string that contains escape characters or starts with a `-` is undefined behavior, and there are a LOT of different implementations of `echo` historically.  So if you want to say `echo hi there` that's fine; it will always work.  But if you want to use backslashes or something like `echo -hi there` that's undefined and you should use `printf` (which is as a much more well-defined interface) instead.